# How can I pass a string containing spaces from Jenkinsfile to bash?

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

I have a bash file which takes multiple arguments, the exact number of which is determined at runtime. This file is called with the arguments by a pipeline in Jenkins. I have troubles passing the arguments in a way that can still be used in the bash script. This will become clearer further down.

The bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java myApp.$1.com $2
```

The corresponding (grossly oversimplified) Jenkinsfile is like this:

```
def subdom= 'example'
def opts= ''
opts += '-test ' 
opts += '-comment=\\"' + "test comment" + '\\"'

pipeline {
    agent any 
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    environment {
        SUBDOM="${subdom}"
        OPTS= "${opts}"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Run') {
            steps('Prepare') {
                script {
                    sh "bash -x /usr/share/jenkins/ref/runApp.sh $SUBDOM \"$OPTS\""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The space in the comment leads to errors. I have to find a way to pass the opts via the shell command in Jenkins.

I have tried putting `opts` into an array which seemed to work, but came out in the bash script as `example '[-test,' '-comment="test comment"]'`. Generally, no matter what I try, I see these single quotes pop up in the bash script and I have no idea where they come from or how I can prevent them. Looking at the logs, they are not present in the Jenkins call, but then appear out of nowhere in the script. Or are they there in the Jenkins call but not in the console output? I remember something about Jenkins being weird like that.

Trying to transform `opts` into a bash array within Jenkins was not fruitful and led to tons of syntax errors in groovy, no amount of escaping seems to be able to get around.

Is there any way to pass `opts` into the bash script? This is truly breaking my brain.

Edit: Suggestions from the comments

```
#!/bin/bash
subdom=$1
shift
java myApp.$subdom.com $@
```

had the quotes present again.

```
#!/bin/bash
subdom=$1
shift
java myApp.$subdom.com << EOF
$@
EOF
```

did not result in any arguments passed to the java app.

Enclosing the shell call in groovy with `"""` had no effect on the mystery quotes.

Comment: The quotes in the `sh` command are probably closed by the quotes in `$opts`. Perhaps you could treat `opts` as multiple arguments instead of a single string argument, remove the quotes in your `sh` command and use `$@` instead of `$1` in your script?

Comment: That is a great idea, what I omitted was that there ar emore parameters that I need in a different way. I have edited the question accordingly. I think your approach does not work then, or is it still possible?

Comment: Have you tried using the Groovy multi-line quotes i.e. `"""` to start and finish the shell command? Have you tried using a `heredoc` in the bash command?

Comment: Maybe unrelated to your question, but in your bash script, $1 and $2 will undergo word splitting. Is this really what you want to achieve?

Comment: @CloudWatcher you could retrieve the first arg with `subDom=$1`, then get rid of the first argument with `shift`, then use `java myApp.$subDom.com $@`

Comment: I tried all these promising suggestions, but non worked. Most failed completey, and the approach using `shift` just brought me back to square one. Somewhere, Jenkins keeps injecting single quotes that I can't get rid of.

Comment: @CloudWatcher, what error happened when you tried `heredoc`? Same for the multi-line comment?

Comment: @Uberhumus Multi-line comment led to the quotes being present once more, `heredoc` swallows all the arguments. I think I may have done that one wrong, but I tried multiple different ways, none worked. I have amended the question with examples.

Comment: @CloudWatcher, try `bash -x << EOF subdom=$1 shift java myApp.$subdom.com $@ EOF` With newlines and separators as required, obviously.

Comment: Shouldn't your script be quoting its args? `java "myApp.$1.com" "$2"` might solve some of this.

Comment: The underlying problem has nothing to do with jenkins or groovy, its related to how the shell handles arguments. In this case you might have to use `eval` shenanigans, i.e. rewrite the java line in your script with `eval java myApp.$1.com $2`, this should get the single argument  `"$OPTS"` split intp multiple again.

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

The problem is not with jenkins. This is how bash interprets the cli arguments.

There is no easy way but the one with fewest steps it could be to encode your arguments with base64

```
script {
  sh "bash runApp.sh aaaa "+'"'+params.foo+'"'
}
```

Then in your script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "param1: $1"
echo "param2: $2"
```

The second parameter will be

[image]

I will show you other options. From the easiest to the advanced

## How cli arguments works

If your script is

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "param1: $1"
echo "param2: $2"
echo "all-params: $@"
```

You should enclose the argument with double quotes if it has blank spaces

[image]

Also you can use **$@** to get access to all the parameters

## Base64

Encode your variable with base64

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('write') {
               steps {
                   script {
                       
def script = '''
#!/bin/bash

variable=$(echo "$1" | base64 --decode)
echo "variable inside bash script: $variable"
'''                       
                       
//just to simulate your deploy.sh file
writeFile(file: 'runApp.sh', text: script)
sh "ls -l"
sh "chmod +x runApp.sh"
sh "cat runApp.sh"
                   }
               }
        }
        
        stage('send params') {
               steps {
                 script {
                    println "received parameter: "+params.foo
                    def encoded = sh(script:"echo $foo | base64", returnStdout:true)
                    println "encoded parameter: "+encoded
                    sh "\$(pwd)/runApp.sh $encoded"
                 }
               }
        }        
    }
}
```

[image]

**Result**

[image]

This also could help you with complex parameters like files or certs or string with special characters

## Environtment variables

Your bash script should not get the values from arguments. It should use the environment variables

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "param1: $VARIABLE_1"
echo "param2: $VARIABLE_2"
```

Then your pipeline should inject the variables:

```
stage('set variables') {
        steps {
            script {
                env.VARIABLE_1 = "hello"
                env.VARIABLE_2 = "hello world"
                sh '$(pwd)/deploy.sh'
            } 
        }
}
```